# I want to validaton condition for two fields Pydantic

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

The task is to make a validator for two dependent fields.
If `MCC` is not empty, then you need to check that `OUTSIDE` is passed in the type field. And vice versa. If `MCC` is empty, then `INSIDE` should be passed in the type field.

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work. Can someone tell me the best way to do this

```
import json

from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass, ValidationError
from pydantic import root_validator, validator
from typing import Union, List, Literal


@dataclass
class DataInclude:
    type: Literal['INSIDE', 'OUTSIDE']
    accountID: Union[None, int]
    date: int
    tranDate: int
    operationType: Literal['CREDIT', 'DEBIT', 'OPEN', 'DV']
    paymentDetailType: Literal[
        'BETWEEN_THEIR', 'INSIDE_BANK', 'EXTERNAL_INDIVIDUAL', 'EXTERNAL_ENTITY', 'OTHER_BANK',
        'HOUSING_AND_COMMUNAL_SERVICE', 'MOBILE', 'INTERNET', 'TRANSPORT', 'TAX_AND_STATE_SERVICE',
        'NOT_FINANCE', 'CONTACT_ADDRESSLESS', 'DIRECT', 'SFP', 'OUTSIDE_CASH', 'INSIDE_OTHER',
        'OUTSIDE_OTHER', 'C2B_PAYMENT', 'INSIDE_DEPOSIT']
    amount: Union[int, float, None]
    documentAmount: Union[int, float, None]
    comment: str
    documentID: int | None
    accountNumber: str
    currencyCodeNumeric: int
    merchantName: str | None
    merchantNameRus: str | None
    groupName: str
    md5hash: str
    svgImage: str | None
    fastPayment: str | None
    terminalCode: str | None
    deviceCode: str | None
    country: str | None
    city: str | None
    operationId: str | None
    isCancellation: bool | None  # BOOL!
    cardTranNumber: str | None
    opCode: int | None
    MCC: int | None
    
    @validator('type', 'MCC')
    def check_passwords_match(cls, values):
        type_operation, mcc = values['type'], values['MCC']
        if mcc is not None:
            if type_operation != "OUTSIDE":
                raise ValueError('MCC NOT EQUAL TYPE OPERATION')
        return values


@dataclass
class MessageResponse:
    statusCode: int
    errorMessage: Union[None, str]
    data: List[DataInclude]

    @staticmethod
    def validation_body(data):
        try:
            data_new = json.loads(data)
            MessageResponse(**data_new)
            return True
        except ValidationError as e:
            raise e
```

I have tried various options. I have read the documentation, but could not find the answer to my question.
I use pydantic for automation api testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this, the validator on `MCC` will have to deal with both your cases.

```
    @validator("MCC")
    def check_passwords_match(cls, v, values):
        if "type" not in values:
            raise ValueError("TYPE VALIDATION FAILED")
        if (v is not None and values["type"] != "OUTSIDE") or (
            v is None and values["type"] != "INSIDE"
        ):
            raise ValueError("MCC NOT EQUAL TYPE OPERATION")
        return v
```